# Replace single dash between numerals with double-dash

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm having trouble working out the syntax for doing a replacement search with regular expressions in emacs. What I want to do is to replace all single dashes `-` which occur between numerals `[0-9]` with a double dash `--`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me with `M-x replace-regexp`

```
Replace-regexp: \([0-9]+\)-\([0-9]+\) with: \1--\2
```

This replaces:

```
12-345
0-1
```

With:

```
12--345
0--1
```

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the pattern:

```
\([0-9]\)-\([0-9]\)
```

with:

```
\1--\2
```